# Merge an interface and new key:value object for function parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I have a list of `Firebase` objects that I search through and I then want to do various things with the object. The problem I am facing is the fact that `Firebase` returns a more complex object than I want to have in my interface. My interface is called `PlaceOnMap` and looks like this:

```
export interface Location {
  address: string,
  latitude: number,
  longitude: number
}
```

The function I want to call should ideally look like this:

```
addPlaceOnMap(mapPoint: { $key: string, PlaceOnMap } ) {
  this.placeOnMapIds.push(mapPoint.$key);
  this.newPlaceOnMap.next(mapPoint.lat, mapPoint.lng);
  this.uploadToFirebase(mapPoint.$key, { 
    name: mapPoint.address, 
    lat: mapPoint.lat, 
    lng: mapPoint.lng 
  });
}
```

The point being, I want to combine the `$key` that I receive from `Firebase` with the keys that my interface `PlaceOnMap` usually has.

For completeness, the stored object I receive from `Firebase` looks like this:

```
{
  address: string,
  latitude: number,
  longitude: number,
  street: string,
  country: string,
  description: string
}
```

I think I could use Typescript's Union but this would not be as clean as I want it to be since I always expect to receive this. I know I could create a new interface but this seems to me like an overkill since I only use it once.

If there is no other way, I will resort to `any` or using two parameters (probably the former).

Comment: You could add the `[name: string]: any;` to you interface to access this keys via `mapPoint[$key]` or add them as optional keys. but i also dont know if I realy understand your request.

Comment: This would work but I would need to modify my interface. While this is a viable way to do it once, I have more use cases e.g. I want to combine my `PlaceOnMap` `interface` with my other interface called `PlaceKeywords` which also comes from a `Firebase` object. Basically, I want to be able to use the interfaces as freely as possible while keeping them as lean and defined as possible.

Comment: You can "merge" interfaces like so: `interface A { foo: any; }` `interface B { bar: any; }` `interface C extends A, B { }`. This way you can have your two seperated interfaces and merge them on demand.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the question.  It's fine for an object you receive to have more properties than you're specifying in your interface.  Does something break if you just use your `PlaceOnMap` interface? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: There is less a problem but the code becomes less clear if I don't properly define arguments. I want to be able to use the defined `$key` and call it this way: `mapPoint.$key`. Technically, you are correct and I could just feed an object that has this. But I want Typescript to check for type errors when I call those functions from somewhere else. Does that make sense? I hoped there was an easy way to combine an interface with a non-interface but I think I have to resort either to your solution or declaring another interface.

Comment: What is a "non-interface"?  I think it would be helpful for you to post code that doesn't work, shows a type error, or forces you to do type assertions you don't think you should do.